# CORS issues when emulating ionic app on iOS

Tags: cordova, ionic3, ionic-cli

I recently updated the `ionic-cli` and I am now trying to emulate an ionic app with the command `ionic cordova emulate ios`.

However, I am getting CORS errors with every api requests

> Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I found that the [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/emulate/) say this about the above command

> Like running cordova emulate directly, but also watches for changes in web assets and provides live-reload functionality with the --livereload option.

It seems like that command also starts a server, which would explain why the origin is `localhost` instead of `file://`.

However, I tried emulating with `cordova emulate ios`, or building the app with `ionic cordova build ios` and running the output with the simulator, but I still get CORS errors.

Emulating on Android works fine and there is a proxy for running the app in the browser.

Any idea if I am on the right track and if there would be a way to emulate from `file://`? Would this problem persists when releasing the app to the App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with CORS on iOS actually did not come from the `ionic-cli`, but from the fact that I switched to using `WKWebView` from `UIWebview`.

[This blog post](http://blog.ionic.io/wkwebview-for-all-a-new-webview-for-ionic/) explains more about WKWebView and why it is much better than its predecessor.

It also mentions this concerning CORS:

> UIWebview, or the older webview in iOS, never actually enforced CORS, but WKWebView does and does not provide a way to disable it. To address this, you need to implement CORS correctly and add the following entry:
>
> Origin: http://localhost:8080
>
> IF this is not possible (you do not own the API), a workaround can be to use the native HTTP plugin, @ionic-native/http.

So I enabled CORS on my api, and everything worked as before.

Comment: It enforces cors even if --consolelogs and --livereload doesnt activated?

Before if the --consolelogs and --livereload not activated the request worked correctly

Comment: No, I was actually wrong about the cause of the problem. I also had recently switched over from `UIWebview` to `WKWebView`, and `WKWebView` does enforce CORS, whereas his predecessor didn't.

Answer (score 0):

try creating an ionic proxy, adding this code to ionic.config.json

```
"proxies": [{
    "path": "/api",
    "proxyUrl": "http://your-server.com"
}]
```

and then call your server simply with `http.get('/api')`

If it still not working, try using the cordova http plugin instead of angular http.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already have a proxy set up when running the app in the browser. Before updating the ionic cli, the app when emulated on iOS had an origin of `file://`, but now the origin is `localhost`. I'm also wondering if the app on the App Store will have the same problem since building for production and release also creates CORS issues.

Comment: i don't thnik prod will fix the issue, but try using https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/ instead of angularjs's http client.

Comment: I actually need to use [authHttp](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt) for authentication with my api, but I'm not sure changing the http client will fix the problem, since it will send the same headers with the requests (and same origin).